# How can I overwrite a method whitout copy the default argument values

Tags: php, oop

I have the following problem:

I have a class B that extends class A.
The class A has a method M that has a first parameter p1 (required) and a second parameter p2 (optional).
p2 has a default value V.
B overwrite the method M, so it's signature is the same as A's M.

I am really worried about a change in default value of p2 (V) on A by some developer that do not imagine it is overwritten by child classes and V is repeated on his M's signatures.

So is possible to create M on a child class of A without repeat V as default value, but keep the behavior?

```
    class A
    {
        public function M($p1, $p2 = 'V')
        {

        }
    }

    class B extends A
    {
        public function M($p1, $p2 = null)
        {
            //do something more
            return parent::M($p1, $p2);
/* 
   if user don't pass $p2, it will be null and will pass null to A::M too. 
   Is not what I want. I would like A::M get his $p2 default value 'V'.
*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could set a class constant on `A` and use that as the default value for both?

Comment: Do you need to allow to call the parent method explicitly with `null`, but use the default parameter when called from the child method with `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is very nice PHP function `func_get_args`

```
<?php

function aa($a, $b = null) {
    var_export([$a, $b, func_get_args()]);
}

aa('1 argument');
aa('second NULL', null);
```

In first case it returns only 1 elements array, so you can detect it is default or passed value.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to say it might be a bit weird to not 'trust' developers to use code in a correct way.

But I have a suggestion, since you control the parent class `A`, you can just add some logic into the implementation that just uses value `V` if `null` was passed.

```
class A {
    public function M($p1, $p2 = 'V') {
       if ($p2 === null) $p2 = 'V';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that throw an exception would be a better solution, as this is a developer error to put a null value in the second parameter

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to change the default value in the subclass implentation? after all, if the default value should be `'V'` for the subclass as well as the parent class, why even allow `null` as default in the first place?

Comment: What if someone _wants_ to pass `null` as the second argument? Passing `null` and not passing anything shouldn't be considered equal.

Comment: Hi commenters, I'm simply showing an example in which the OP's  problem can be solved. They _want_ to pass null. They _don't want_ to throw an an exception in this  case. So your comments might make sense in a different scenario, but afaik this solves OP's problem. Whether this is good design or not is  kind of aside the point.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the type of `$p2` in `A`. Then it won't accept a null value.

```
class A
{
    public function M($p1, string $p2 = 'V')
    {

    }
}
```

The `M` method in the child class can still have a `null` default value, which is fine. People *should* be able to change default values when they extend a class. They can change the entire behavior of the `M` method if they want to. But if it calls `parent::M($p1, $p2);` without assigning a string you'll get a type error. The situation you need to handle is the one where *your code* does something unexpected.